# how can i detect click in any frame on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that hides a div when something in the document is clicked. but it only works in its frame. it doesnt detect document clicks in other frames  on the webpage. i've tired `$(parent).click(` but it doesnt work. is there any way?

```
 $(function (){

        $(document).click(

                function (e){

                   ...

                    }  
            )

    })
```

Comment: I don't think that events bubble out of `<iframe>` documents ...

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is the window object of the parent frame. Use

```
$(window.parent.document).click( ... )
```

This will only work if the parent document is on the same domain as the frame document.

Comment: window.parent.document doesnt work but window worked the same as document